# XPath: How to select nodes which have no attributes?

Tags: xpath

Using XPath, how to select nodes which have no attributes (where attribute count = 0)?

For example:

```
<nodes>
    <node attribute1="aaaa"></node>
    <node attribute1="bbbb"></node>
    <node></node> <- FIND THIS
</nodes>
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
//node[not(@*)]
```

That's the XPath to select all nodes named "node" in the document without any attributes.

Comment: This is nice, but it still finds `<node class=""></node>` anything we can do about it?

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki see answer below to address this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes/43910689#43910689

Answer (score 24):

```
//node[count(@*)=0]
```

Will select all <node> with zero attributes

Answer (score 11):

To address Marek Czaplicki's comment and expand the answer

```
//node[not(@*) or not(string-length(@*))]
```

....will select all node elements with zero attributes OR which have attributes that are all empty. If it was just a particular attribute you are interested in, rather than all of them, then you could use

```
//node[not(@attribute1) or not(string-length(@attribute1))]
```

...and this would select all node elements that either don't have an attribute called `attribute1` OR which have an `attribute1` attribute that is empty.

That is, the following elements would be picked out by either of these xpath expressions

```
<nodes>
    <node attribute1="aaaa"></node>
    <node attribute1=""></node> <!--This one -->
    <node attribute1="bbbb"></node>
    <node></node> <!--...and this one -->
</nodes>
```

See jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7yucas3x/)