# xpath: how can i query for an element named test with no attributes at all?

Tags: xpath

I would like to be able to find an element named 'test' with no attributes at all.

How can I do that using XPATH?

If i just query for `/test` it finds me all the `test` elements even with the ones that contain attributes.

example:

```
<main>
<test id="test1">txt</test>
<test>txt2</test>
</main>
```

Querying for `//test` will find me both of the elements. I want only the one that contains no attributes. I can query for `//test[not(@id)]` but I was wondering if there is a command for an element with no attributes at all.

Comment: Is there something that will distinguish the element to make it unique? Or are you saying that it will be the only element with no attributes while all the others will have attributes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: How to select nodes which have no attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it.  If you want to find the the `test` element(s) that have no attributes at all, use a wildcard match for the attribute name in your predicate filter:

```
//test[not(@*)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query for `test`.

http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: that doesn't really help me. i updated main post with more info

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<test>
Oh hai
</test>
```

test = /test
Oh hai = /test/text()

Not sure about your actual intent.