# How to select a node without attributes using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Let say that I have xml like this:

```
<root>
    <node light="somevalue">message1</node>
    <node dark="somevalue">message2</node>
    <node>message3</node>
</root>
```

With xpath usage I need to get "message3".

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: How to select nodes which have no attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to select nodes without attributes.

From [XPath: How to select nodes which have no attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes)

```
//node[not(@*)]
```

This will select all nodes that do not have attributes.

Comment: ``<xsl:for-each select="//node[not(@*)]">`` doesn't work for me using stylesheets version 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

```
/root/node[not(@*)]/text()
```