# How to get element without attributes by XPath

Tags: xpath

I want to get an td element without attributes.

For example:
My code:

```
<td class="yyy">1234</td>
<td>5678</td>
```

I want to get: 5678
What the XPath for that?

Thank,
Chani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of several other SO questions:

See this:

[XPath: How to select nodes which have no attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes)

Which recommends:

```
//node[not(@*)]
```

Where node is your nodename.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
  /td[not(@class)]
```

Comment: Well replace it with whatever you want then.

Comment: OK, but the problem was that I didn't know what or how much are the attributes. any way, I got my answer: "*"

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
.//td[. = '5678']
```

or

```
.//td[text() = '5678']
```

--

if it is important that there are no attributes then,

```
.//td[text() = '5678' and not(@*)]
```

--

or, if you want to get the inner text of the first `td` with no attributes.

```
.//td[not(@*)][1]/text()
```