# How to select all nodes which have no attributes using rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

Using    `rvest`, how to select nodes which have no attributes?

For example:

```
<nodes>
    <node attribute1="aaaa"></node>
    <node attribute1="bbbb"></node>
    <node></node> <- FIND THIS
</nodes>
```

Here is a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323755/xpath-how-to-select-nodes-which-have-no-attributes/43910689#43910689) using XPath, but when I try in `rvest` with something similar to

```
wp %>% html_read(.) %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//node[not(@*)")
```

where `wp` is the desired url, I error out with:

```
Warning message:
In xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf) :
  Invalid predicate [1206]
```

when I can see what I desire to scrape has no attributes in the page source.

To be frank, I just don't know enough about web development and HTML to understand how to generalize this example to rvest's doumentation. Any help or resources would be much appreciated!

### EDIT:

The correct code to achieve this in `rvest` is

```
wp %>% html_read(.) %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//node[not(@*)]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just missing a closing square bracket:

```
library(rvest)

"<nodes>
    <node attribute1=\"aaaa\" attribute2=\"cccc\"></node>
    <node attribute1=\"bbbb\"></node>
    <node></node>
</nodes>" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//node[not(@*)]")
```

gives

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <node></node>
```

Comment: I am so sorry to have wasted your time! The thrown error made me think it was a logical error. Thank you so much. I appreciate you kindly letting me know it was just syntactic error